# Proxy pac file doesn't work anymore in Chrome and Edge

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge, http-proxy, autoproxy

I have a pac file hosted by my company server and it stopped working.
We didn't made any change and the content is :

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (dnsDomainIs(host, ".mydomain.com")) {
    return "DIRECT";
  }

  if (dnsDomainIs(host, "fonts.googleapis.com")) {
    return "DIRECT";
  }
   if (dnsDomainIs(host, "fonts.gstatic.com")) {
    return "DIRECT";
  }

  return "PROXY http://0.0.0.0:8080";
}
```

I can download the pac file by typing the url in the browser so he is still hosted, it still working in firefox but not chrome or edge.

It should block all other websites except "mydomain", we use it during online tests and to block students going in google or others websites looking for questions answers.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have enough environments to test this problem. Are there any error messages in the console? And you can try rolling back your browser version to test if this issue still occurs.

Comment: No, no error messages at all. And it doesnt work in both Edge and Chrome.

Comment: If this is the case, I suggest you could report your issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list